# 1000000 to 1M and 1000 to 1K in oracle query

Tags: oracle

i want to show numeric digits as given below by using an oracle query:

```
1000000  1M
  22000 22k
```

Please help is there any way to do it in oracle query??

Comment: `22500 => 22.5k` and `1500000 => 1.5M`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard function (except for the scientific notation), but you can define such a function yourself:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (SELECT power(10, ROWNUM) num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9)
  2  SELECT num,
  3         CASE
  4            WHEN num >= 1e6 THEN
  5             round(num / 1e6) || 'M'
  6            WHEN num >= 1e3 THEN
  7             round(num / 1e3) || 'k'
  8            ELSE to_char(num)
  9         END conv
 10    FROM DATA;

       NUM CONV
---------- -----------------------------------------
        10 10
       100 100
      1000 1k
     10000 10k
    100000 100k
   1000000 1M
  10000000 10M
 100000000 100M
1000000000 1000M
```